# Send data from JSP to database postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc

Hi I wouldlike to send data (my object Tab2D is array in 2 dimensions) from JSP to database postgres :

My table Conteneur in postgres have column type bytea

MyMapWebServices :

```
@PutMapping(value="/add")
    public void saveMap(String identifiant){
        Map myMap = new Map();
        myMap.getNewMap(identifiant);

        conteneurDao.save(myMap);
    }
```

MyMapServices :

```
public Tab2D [][] getNewMap (String identifiant)

Tab2D [][] tabs = new Tab2D [3][3]

// Some code 

return tab2
```

ConteneurDao :

```
@Repository
public interface ConteneurDao extends JpaRepository<Conteneur, Integer> {

    Conteneur findByIdentifiant(String identifiantConteneur);
}
```

I don't know how can I do this ?

**EDIT** : I tried with save method but it doesn't work

Comment: `new Map()`, what is Map ? or won't compile.

Comment: @PeterMmm I failed sorry... I don't know how to close this topic... Here my new topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60668063/how-to-send-data-from-jsp-to-data-postgres