# How to send data from JSP to data postgres?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I woudlike to send data from my back to postgres database.

Actually I have a class Car DAO :

```
 @Repository
    public interface CarDao extends JpaRepository<Car, Integer> {

        Car findByIdentifiant(String identifiantCar);

        @Transactional
        @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
        @Query("UPDATE Car SET ctn_map = :map WHERE ctn_identifiant = :identifiant")
        void updateCar(@Param("identifiant") String identifiantCar, @Param("map") Cell[][] cell);

    }
```

MapWebServices :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Map")
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:4200", "http://100.105.100.10"})
public class MapWebServices {

    @Autowired
    MapService MapService;
    @Autowired
    CarDao CarDao;

    @GetMapping(value = "/all", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Cell[][] getMapGlobal() {
        saveMapLocale("Audi");
        return MapService.getMapGlobal();
    }

    public void saveMapLocale(String identifiantCar){
        CarDao.updateCar(identifiantCar, MapService.getMapGlobal());
    }

}
```

My goal is to update my array column of my table (Car)

Comment: Update in a GET request ? That is weired. Anyway, what get you ? Unexpected result, Exception ?

Comment: @PeterMmm when I go to this URL : `localhost4200/SNAPSHOT/all` I have this error : `There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not serialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not seria`